# How do I fix my "PHP Warning: A non-numeric value encountered" error?

Tags: php

I have read through many other posts about this non-numeric value encountered error, but unfortunately, I may be dense.  I'm not sure how to fix this annoying error.

Here is my code block:

```
 foreach ($local_words as $local_word_to_check){

                $letters = mb_str_split($local_word_to_check);
                $letters = array_map( 'addslashes', $letters );

                $local_total_letter_box_length = "";

                $query2 = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Alpha) AS Alpha,
                                 GROUP_CONCAT(Letter_Box_Width) AS Letter_Box_Width
                          FROM Font_Krinkes
                          WHERE Alpha IN ('" . implode("','", $letters) . "')";

                $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $query2) or die("unable to query database!");

                if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
                    $widths = array_combine(explode(',', $row['Alpha']), explode(',', $row['Letter_Box_Width']));
                    $total_word_box_width = 0;
                    foreach (mb_str_split($local_word_to_check) as $letter) {
                        $local_total_letter_box_length += $widths[$letter];
                    }
                }

                $complete_font_values[] = $local_total_letter_box_length;  

                unset($letters);
        }
```

The error happens on this line:

```
$local_total_letter_box_length += $widths[$letter];
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Code is working fine ..or its giving the fatal error or just warnig?

Comment: `$local_total_letter_box_length = 0;` instead on `$local_total_letter_box_length = "";`

Comment: @NigelRen me neither, I'm still asking for more clarity so that I can offer further help to the OP.  There are surely points to refine in this snippet.

Comment: How many records are in `Font_Krinkes`, if you could just read in all the records before the loop it would save a repeated read.

Comment: Is it sensible for your program logic to remove duplicates from `$letters` before querying?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$local_total_letter_box_length = "";` is a string when it is first declared.

`$local_total_letter_box_length += $widths[$letter]`

That's not how you concatenate a string in php.

Use `.=` to concatenate.

---

If you mean to increase a numeric value, declare your variable with `0`.

`+=` is okay to use on numeric values and arrays.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/W1oLT))

```
$integer = 5;
$integer += 10;
echo $integer , "\n---\n";


$array = ['good' => 'one'];
$array += ['two'];
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
15
---
array (
  'good' => 'one',
  0 => 'two',
)
```

Comment: About using prepared statements with a variable number of values in `IN()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48452420/2943403

Comment: Shouldn't use be using the multibyte version here: `str_split()`?  I am struggling to follow your code logic without some sample data.  Hopefully my answer is helpful.

Comment: Hi.  I set to $local_total_letter_box_length = "0", and this solved the problem.  Also, yes, you found another error. :)  I did not update to mb_str_split lower in the code.    Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I've got to be honest, I don't like the look of those GROUP BY calls, just use `array_combine(explode(',', $row['Alpha']), explode(',', $row['Letter_Box_Width']))` to break it all apart again.  If you show me your desired output, some sample rows and table schema, I may be able to offer some refinements.

Comment: Replace 2nd `mb_str_split($local_word_to_check)` call (in the foreach()) with `$letters`.

Comment: Not sure how I show you the entire block and desired output in a readable format in this small comment section.  Where should I paste it?  What is the norm for this site when the topic of conversation is expanded beyond the original question?

Comment: pastebin.com is a decent place to store it online and pass a hyperlink as a comment

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$local_total_letter_box_length = 0;
```

Instead of

```
$local_total_letter_box_length = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of time, this error happens when used `"+"` as strings concatenation operator like other languages, but in PHP strings concatenation operator is `"."`, if you have numberic value as string you have to cast it like `$num = (int) "10" + (int) "20";`